# Can't use PHPickerViewController delegate with KMM

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform, compose-ios

I'm trying to use the UiKit API PHPickerViewController using KMM and Compose for iOS.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.interop.LocalUIViewController
import platform.PhotosUI.PHPickerConfiguration
import platform.PhotosUI.PHPickerViewController
import platform.PhotosUI.PHPickerViewControllerDelegateProtocol
import platform.darwin.NSObject

@Composable
actual fun pickerController() {
    val uiViewController = LocalUIViewController.current
    val configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
    val pickerController = PHPickerViewController(configuration)
    val pickerDelegate = object : NSObject(), PHPickerViewControllerDelegateProtocol {
        override fun picker(picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking: List<*>) {
            println("didFinishPicking: $didFinishPicking")
            picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag = false, completion = {})
            uiViewController.dismissModalViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
    }

    pickerController.setDelegate(pickerDelegate)
    uiViewController.presentViewController(pickerController, animated = false, completion = null)
}
```

This displays the image picker:
[image]

Unfortunately, when clicking on *Cancel*, the delegate callback is not called, and I get the following message on the console:

```
[Picker] PHPickerViewControllerDelegate doesn't respond to picker:didFinishPicking:
```

Is it possible to implement the callback in Kotlin?
What am I missing?

Comment: there's a chance `pickerDelegate` is released - `setDelegate` doesn't increase reference counter of delegate object, in Swift this object would've been released right after exiting `pickerController` function, not sure how it works with kotlin memory model, but I would've stored it somehow

Comment: Thank you for the hint @PhilDukhov! I tried to persist the delegate in a global property but unfortunately it doesn't solve the issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `pickerDelegate` is `NSObject`, it's lifecycle follows ObjC rules, not KMM memory model.

So as soon as the execution leaves composable block, this objects gets released - as `setDelegate` takes it as weak reference.

You can fix it by storing it using `remember`.

Also using your function is dangerous because you're gonna call `presentViewController` on each recomposition - e.g. if some of your reactive data changes on the calling side.

You can update it to return an action that will present it, but store delegate and the action itself using `remember`:

```kotlin
@Composable
actual fun rememberOpenPickerAction(): () -> Unit {
    val uiViewController = LocalUIViewController.current
    val pickerDelegate = remember {
        object : NSObject(), PHPickerViewControllerDelegateProtocol {
            override fun picker(picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking: List<*>) {
                println("didFinishPicking: $didFinishPicking")
                picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag = false, completion = {})
            }
        }
    }

    return remember {
        {
            val configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
            val pickerController = PHPickerViewController(configuration)
            pickerController.setDelegate(pickerDelegate)
            uiViewController.presentViewController(pickerController, animated = true, completion = null)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
Button(onClick = rememberOpenPickerAction()) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Phil. I have a question:
after we pick the image we receive - didFinishPicking: List<*>
after that we need to cast that to - didFinishPicking.first() as PHPickerResult
from there we get the itemProvider, but after that I need to call itemProvider.loadObjectOfClass, but I don't know what to pass... in iOS its itemProvider.loadObjectOfClass(UIImage.self). What is the representation in kotlin? Thanks

Comment: @LubomirBabev that's a good question, I have no idea. It feels like `Class` from objc is not translated correctly, as kotlin expects for `NSItemProviderReadingProtocol`, but it should expect `KClass<NSItemProviderReadingProtocol>` or `ObjCClass`. You should fill an issue on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/.

Comment: Okay but what's the point of using PHPickerViewController if you can't retrieve the image ... ?

I have another question, could you please check it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77080180/5519005

Comment: @LubomirBabev try [this](https://github.com/MohamedRejeb/Calf/blob/d41a41c002cf3ead5889659401930bdcd1312852/calf-file-picker/src/iosMain/kotlin/com.mohamedrejeb.calf.picker/FilePickerLauncher.ios.kt#L23)

Comment: Thank you. That was what I'm looking for. I upvote your answers now. Please check the question in the last comment. :)

Comment: @LubomirBabev you can take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268654/how-to-handle-callback-from-phpickerviewcontroller-in-a-kmm-project