# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not called when using UIImagePickerController in KMM (Compose Multiplatform)

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I'm trying to use UIImagePickerController in KMM project (Compose Multiplatform)

```
@Composable
actual fun ImagePickerView() {
    var bitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }
    Box {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .padding(bottom = 32.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            bitmap?.let {
                Image(bitmap = it, contentDescription = null)
            }
            Button(
                onClick = rememberOpenPickerAction { image ->
                    bitmap = image
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Select Image")
            }
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
                onClick = rememberOpenCameraAction { image ->
                    bitmap = image
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Take photo")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberOpenPickerAction(onImageSelected:(ImageBitmap) -> Unit): () -> Unit {
    val uiViewController = LocalUIViewController.current
    val galleryDelegate = remember {
        object : NSObject(), UIImagePickerControllerDelegateProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegateProtocol {
            override fun imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: Map<Any?, *>) {
                val uiImage = didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
                uiImage?.let { onImageSelected(it.toImageBitmap()) }
                picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag = false, completion = {})
            }
        }
    }

    return remember {
        {
            val galleryController = UIImagePickerController()
            galleryController.setSourceType(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary)
            galleryController.setAllowsEditing(true)
            galleryController.setDelegate(galleryDelegate)
            uiViewController.presentViewController(galleryController, animated = true, completion = null)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberOpenCameraAction(onImageSelected:(ImageBitmap) -> Unit): () -> Unit {
    val uiViewController = LocalUIViewController.current
    val cameraDelegate = remember {
        object : NSObject(), UIImagePickerControllerDelegateProtocol, UINavigationControllerDelegateProtocol {
            override fun imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: Map<Any?, *>) {
                val uiImage = didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
                uiImage?.let { onImageSelected(it.toImageBitmap()) }
                picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag = false, completion = {})
            }
        }
    }

    return remember {
        {
            val cameraController = UIImagePickerController()
            cameraController.setSourceType(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
            cameraController.setAllowsEditing(true)
            cameraController.setCameraCaptureMode(UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode.UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto)
            cameraController.setDelegate(cameraDelegate)
            uiViewController.presentViewController(cameraController, animated = true, completion = null)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using actual composable function for choosing pick file from gallery, take picture or choose document file. With gallery pick and document file everything works perfect. But when I take photo from camera app, the `imagePickerController` is never called.

Does anyone can help me resolve this problem ?
Am I missing something ?

Comment: There's a lot of irrelevant code here. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe the only irrelevant part is with the document picker. The gallery picker and take photo are relevant because both of them use UIImagePickerController. In case with sourceType .photoLibrary everything works, but in case with sourceType .camera the callback method after taking photo is never called.

Comment: Most probably this problem is not related to KMP, try using swift analog and look for iOS solutions